# Anything like Resharper for C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli, resharper

Call me spoiled. But I am so used to reverse programming style with Resharper in C#. For example, call non-existing method in a class and Resharper will create it for you with few key strokes. Now I am writing C++/CLI for client and Resharper does not support C++/CLI. This is slowing me down. Is there anything like Resharper for C++/CLI?

Comment: It seems some of the R# competitors support C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611977/refactor-pro-versus-visual-assist-x-for-c-development

Comment: @millimoose Your comment seems to be an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit 1: Just a quick update to my previous answer , Jetbrains have since released Resharper for C++ which is just awesome - there are some limitations and not as powerful as Resharper for c# ( yet!) due to inherent nature of parsing c++ but they keep adding improvements - 
[Resharper for C++.](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/whatsnew/)

I have used 
http://www.wholetomato.com/

For c++ cli though not as feature packed as r# it is very east to use and powerful. Has increase productivity many folds. I would recommend this.